# How do I include the commit description in a --pretty git log?

Tags: git, github

Since the GitHub Mac app started discouraging me from writing long summary text in my commits, I've been using the Description field to start recording more details.

I use my git logs to generate a changelog like this:

```
> git log --pretty=%s --since "last wednesday"
Prevents a double 'error #8' message
This should be part of e074d5b
Logging out while offline is problematic...
Make the Pinterest sharing choices less ambiguous
Sometimes the download buttons disappeared
Downloading wasn't prompting subscriptions on iPad
```

However, now I'd like to include the description text so I don't miss any details when updating my changelog this way. I don't see anything about `description` in the list on this page of the git book http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, found it by going through `git help log`.

`git log --pretty='%s %b'` does the trick.